# Android Sharing Photo and Text together using ShareOpenGraphObject

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to post image and text together thorough my android app  but the share dialog appears with post link disabled and even the window disappears itself after few seconds with error: Failed to generate preview for user.. something wrong in my code?
[image]
[image]

```
SharePhoto photo1 = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bi)
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(recUrl))
                .build();

        ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                .putString("og:type", "healthsynergy.photo")
                .putString("og:title", "food")
                .putString("og:description", "This is a wonderful food.")
                .putPhoto("og:image",photo1)
                .build();


        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType("healthsynergy.publish_actions")
                .putObject("photo", object)
                .build();
        ShareOpenGraphContent content1 = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName("photo")
                .setAction(action)
                .build();


        shareDialog.show(content1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is not possible to post OG action without "image" set, even if you have images in shared object.